# file splits into many parts in flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

Hi I am trying to load the csv file from local file system to HDFS file system through flume.I have only one file for parsing.The file size is less than 5mb, But it splits into many parts while parsing it on flume.here is my flume conf.

```
FileAgent.sources = tail
FileAgent.channels = Channel-2
FileAgent.sinks = HDFS
FileAgent.sources.tail.type = exec
FileAgent.sources.tail.command = cat /tmp/flumeSpool/2.csv
FileAgent.sources.tail.channels = Channel-2

FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://127.0.0.1:54310/
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = Channel-2
FileAgent.channels.Channel-2.type = file

FileAgent.channels.Channel-2.capacity = 100000
FileAgent.channels.Channel-2.transactionCapacity = 80000
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
FileAgent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 10485760
FileAgent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
FileAgent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 300
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have made mistake in the flume conf file itself.

```
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
FileAgent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 10485760
FileAgent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
FileAgent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 300
```

You have given sink name as k1 while you defined it as HDFS in start.
Rewrite it as follows:

```
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text  
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 10485760
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0
FileAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 300
```

Because of wrongname  sink is taking default values for following configurations which are :
roll size = 1024 (bytes)
roll count = 10 (events)
Hence many files.
(In case k1 is some other sink in same conf file then mention all these parameters for HDFS sink as well )